# This is the error that i got "Unable to access resource" Flutter Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

when i run this function that i got this error that "Unable to access resource". 
all the .wav files are present inside the assets/audio folder.

**And i have written this function inside the lib/main.dart** file[image]

[image]

all the files are present in the audio folder like this

[image]

```
  **i also added the assets in pubspc.yml file**          

name: flutter_audio
description: Demonstrates how to use the flutter_audio_recorder plugin.
publish_to: 'none'

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  #flutter_audio_recorder_example: ^1.1.0
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider: ^1.1.0
  file: ^5.0.4
  audioplayers: ^0.13.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_audio_recorder: ^0.5.5


  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:    

  assets:
   - assets/audio/2din16.wav
   - assets/audio/amb16.wav
```

Comment: Show your pubspec.yaml and replace your image of code with text in the question

Comment: # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/audio/2din16.wav
   - assets/audio/amb16.wav

Comment: Show the pubspec.yaml How you adding it there! Exact format!

Comment: i have added this

Comment: yes I can see... I don't see any problem with it.. Make sure you also import them with 'pub get' in you pubsbec.yaml and also try to remove those 2 dots which I can not paste here to show you which one I mean because you got the code in the image

Comment: Did it help - `await audioPlayer.play("assets/audio/2din16.wav", isLocal:true);` ?

Comment: actually it solve the error when i restart the application not the hot reload.

Answer (score 1):

Use asset path like :

```
await audioPlayer.play("assets/audio/2din16.wav", isLocal:true);
```